# Effective database structure for high traffic

Tags: sql, database

We are looking at restructuring our database. We currently list about 60,000 boats tracking views per boat in months this is updated on each boat pageview. The current database is like;

```
BoatID   Year   Month    Views
1554     2013   2        124
1554     2013   3        1542
```

We would like to store information daily in this kind of structure(see below) will this have any strain on the database?(in one year we will have a minimum of 60,000 x 365 = 21,360,000 rows)

```
BoatID   Date         Views
1554     01/02/2013   20
1554     02/02/2013   142
```

About our site - we receive around 6,000,000 to 7,000,000 page views a month. We have a dedicated database server running sql2008 - quad-core 2.2 x 2, 24gb ram.

Comment: Determining the strain for your database based upon removing 1 column would be impossible for us to determine.  You would have to investigate this yourself using the execution plan and tuning adviser and see how your queries perform.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your existing structure is that you are limited to providing a high level overview of the views for each boat. You can only show the views based on month/year.  If you ever want to drill-down into the data to see what days have more views or activity, you can't.

The second structure gives you more flexibility when it comes to reporting, date comparisons, etc.

As far as performance of your queries you will need to use the execution plan and query tuning to determine how queries will perform.

Answer (score 0):

The new design looks fine.

If I calculated correctly, you are getting (on average) less than 1 request per second. Even if we double it (some people sleep during nights), that's 2 requests per second.

I have a strong feeling, that the database server you mentioned will be able to handle it.

Some ideas:

- check whether your application can cache view hits and perform inserts/updates every, say 10 views
- make sure you index your table correctly to minimize query time, it will take little time to update a row
- if you have low traffic during night, you can make a job which would insert new entries for each boat daily; for heavily indexed tables inserts may be very costly; it's an idea, I haven't tested it or used it, ever...

Comment: Thanks, think i will try cache the view hits and do a insert/update every 5 mins, i will update when i get results.